# Crawlera not working with Scrapy, downloader not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, web-crawler

Was trying to implement [Common Practices](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#avoiding-getting-banned) in scrapy. So tried to implement the **crawlera** library.

I installed and set up **Crawlera** as mentioned [here](http://crawlera.com/usage). (I can see the  `scrapylib` library in my system by doing `help('modules')`)

This is my **`settings.py`** for scrapy:

```
BOT_NAME = 'cnn'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['cnn.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'cnn.spiders'
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {'scrapylib.crawlera.CrawleraMiddleware': 600,'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,}
CRAWLERA_ENABLED = True
CRAWLERA_USER = 'abc'
CRAWLERA_PASS = 'abc@abc'
```

But when I run the spider nothing happens.

I can see in my scrapy log that **CrawleraMiddleware** is loaded:

```
2013-12-23 20:12:54+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CrawleraMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
```

why is it not crawling?

This is the log with **`Crawlera` Enabled**:

```
2013-12-23 21:58:14+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.20.2 started (bot: cnn)
2013-12-23 21:58:14+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2013-12-23 21:58:14+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'cnn.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'news.json', 'MEMDEBUG_ENABLED': True, 'RETRY_ENABLED': False, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['cnn.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'cnn', 'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 240, 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'MEMUSAGE_REPORT': True, 'REDIRECT_ENABLED': False, 'MEMUSAGE_ENABLED': True}
2013-12-23 21:58:14+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: FeedExporter, LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, MemoryUsage, MemoryDebugger, SpiderState
2013-12-23 21:58:14+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, CrawleraMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-12-23 21:58:14+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2013-12-23 21:58:14+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2013-12-23 21:58:14+0530 [cnn] INFO: Spider opened
2013-12-23 21:58:14+0530 [cnn] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-12-23 21:58:14+0530 [cnn] INFO: Using crawlera at http://proxy.crawlera.com:8010 (user: xmpirate)
2013-12-23 21:58:14+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2013-12-23 21:58:14+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-12-23 21:58:15+0530 [cnn] DEBUG: Crawled (407) <GET http://www.example1.com> (referer: None)
2013-12-23 21:58:15+0530 [cnn] DEBUG: Crawled (407) <GET http://www.example2.com> (referer: None)
2013-12-23 21:58:15+0530 [cnn] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-12-23 21:58:15+0530 [cnn] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 464,
     'downloader/request_count': 2,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 364,
     'downloader/response_count': 2,
     'downloader/response_status_count/407': 2,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 23, 16, 28, 15, 679961),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 8,
     'log_count/INFO': 4,
     'memusage/max': 30236737536,
     'memusage/startup': 30236737536,
     'response_received_count': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 23, 16, 28, 14, 853975)}
2013-12-23 21:58:15+0530 [cnn] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

and this is with **`Crawlera` Disabled**:

```
2013-12-23 22:00:45+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.20.2 started (bot: cnn)
2013-12-23 22:00:45+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2013-12-23 22:00:45+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'cnn.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'news.json', 'MEMDEBUG_ENABLED': True, 'RETRY_ENABLED': False, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['cnn.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'cnn', 'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 240, 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False, 'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'MEMUSAGE_REPORT': True, 'REDIRECT_ENABLED': False, 'MEMUSAGE_ENABLED': True}
2013-12-23 22:00:46+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled extensions: FeedExporter, LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, MemoryUsage, MemoryDebugger, SpiderState
2013-12-23 22:00:46+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, CrawleraMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2013-12-23 22:00:46+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2013-12-23 22:00:46+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Enabled item pipelines: 
2013-12-23 22:00:46+0530 [cnn] INFO: Spider opened
2013-12-23 22:00:46+0530 [cnn] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2013-12-23 22:00:46+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 0.0.0.0:6023
2013-12-23 22:00:46+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 0.0.0.0:6080
2013-12-23 22:00:46+0530 [cnn] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.example1.com> (referer: None)
2013-12-23 22:00:47+0530 [cnn] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.example2.com> (referer: None)
**Pages are crawled here**
2013-12-23 22:01:00+0530 [cnn] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2013-12-23 22:01:00+0530 [cnn] INFO: Stored json feed (7 items) in: news.json
2013-12-23 22:01:00+0530 [cnn] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 10151,
     'downloader/request_count': 36,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 36,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 762336,
     'downloader/response_count': 36,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 35,
     'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 23, 16, 31, 0, 376888),
     'item_scraped_count': 7,
     'log_count/DEBUG': 49,
     'log_count/INFO': 4,
     'memusage/max': 30157045760,
     'memusage/startup': 30157045760,
     'request_depth_max': 1,
     'response_received_count': 36,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 36,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 36,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 36,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 36,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 23, 16, 30, 46, 61019)}
2013-12-23 22:01:00+0530 [cnn] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Show ur spider code ?

Comment: @ajkumar25 Does it have anything to do with the spider code? I think importing the `Crawlera' module is what not working here.May be I'm wrong. But still if it's required then u can take any basic **CrawlSpider** example as **[here](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example)**

Comment: does spider crawl with crawlera middleware disabled? showing the complete log with and without crawlera middleware enabled can help debug your issue.

Comment: yes the spider crawl with the crawlera middleware disabled.

Comment: @dangra updated the question with logs.

Comment: See the http status code 407 with the crawlera. Most likely crawler is using some default proxy configuration.

Comment: @Biswanath How do I do that?

Comment: Can you try this   curl -x proxy.crawlera.com:8010 -U USER:PASS http://crawlera.com with your USER and PASS ?

Comment: @Biswanath Yup that's working! In verbose mode it prints out the HTML/CSS

Comment: @Biswanath Also I do get this in log messages of scrapy: `2013-12-27 14:56:07+0530 [cnn] INFO: Using crawlera at http://proxy.crawlera.com:8010 (user: USERNAME)` but it doesn't crawl anything.

Comment: @whoIsCraig, The only thing I can say is now is try to run from different environment Or Can you pass your whole code with crawlera account( or may be I can create a trial one) ?

Answer (score 0):

A 407 error code from Crawlera is an authentication error, there's possibly a typo in the APIKEY or perhaps you are not using the correct one.

[Source](https://support.scrapinghub.com/topics/2290-crawlera-scrapy-and-https/)